# Trouble with aligning numbers

Tags: java, netbeans-8

My apologies if an answer to a question like this already exists, I am an extremely novice coder, and I may have failed to locate it.

I'm working on a project to give the distance, perimeter, and area given the x and y values of three points. Said points are supposed to be rounded to the thousandths place, using the printf command.

It is supposed to look like this:

Triangle ={(8.500 ,1.250) ,(2.500 ,1.250) ,(2.500 ,9.250)}

Yet, I can only manage to get:

Triangle = { ( 8.5001.2502.5001.2502.5009.250

Here is my code:

```
public class TriangleCalculator 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  System.out.println("Enter the x- and y- coordinates of the first point");
  Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner (System.in);
    double pointOneX = keyBoard.nextDouble();
    double pointOneY = keyBoard.nextDouble();
          System.out.println("Enter the x- and y- coordinates of the second point");
    double pointTwoX = keyBoard.nextDouble();
    double pointTwoY = keyBoard.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the x- and y- coordinates of the third point");
    double pointThreeX = keyBoard.nextDouble();
    double pointThreeY = keyBoard.nextDouble();

  System.out.printf("Triangle = { ( %.3f", pointOneX);
  System.out.printf("%.3f", pointOneY);
  System.out.printf("%.3f", pointTwoX);
  System.out.printf("%.3f", pointTwoY);
  System.out.printf("%.3f", pointThreeX);
  System.out.printf("%.3f", pointThreeY);
 }

}
```

If anyone could tell or show how to properly write the printf statement or how to align my code properly, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Notice the brackets and spaces yu added in `
  System.out.printf("Triangle = { ( %.3f", pointOneX);` and think through where else you need spaces and commas and brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything about alignment in your question, only rounding and formatting.

You can, and in this case I think you should, handle multiple data items in one `printf` call:

```
System.out.printf ("Triangle ={(%.3f ,%.3f) ,(%.3f ,%.3f) ,(%.3f ,%.3f)}",
    pointOneX, pointOneY, pointTwoX, pointTwoY, pointThreeX, pointThreeY);
```

This is for the unusual spacing in your example. For no space before each comma, or space before *and after* each comma, or space *only after* each comma, adjust the format string accordingly.

Remember that `printf` does not terminate the output line. If you want that, in portable code add `%n` at the end of the format string, or for Unix or Windows specifically `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: I see what you mean. I attempted to do that type of formatting intitially, but I was intermixing the actual format codes and variables. I believed that there was a way to simply use one `printf` statement, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will not add the parenthesis by itself.

Try:

```
System.out.printf("%.3f", pointOneY);
System.out.printf("),(");
System.out.printf("%.3f", pointTwoX);
System.out.printf("%.3f", pointTwoY);
System.out.printf("),(");    
System.out.printf("%.3f", pointThreeX);
System.out.printf("%.3f", pointThreeY);
System.out.printf(")}");
```